# Suspiciously high accuracy for binary classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Based on the layer function

```
def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation_fn=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.get_shape()[1])
        stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs)
        init = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev)
        W = tf.Variable(init, name="kernel")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        if activation_fn is not None:
            return activation_fn(Z)
        else:
            return Z
```

The following network for a binary classification problem is constructed:

```
n_hidden1 = 100
n_hidden2 = 120
n_outputs = 1 # single value prediction
n_inputs = X_test.shape[1]

reset_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name="y")

layer1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, "layer1", activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = neuron_layer(layer1, n_hidden2, "layer2", activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
prediction = neuron_layer(layer2, n_outputs, "output",activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid)
cost = tf.losses.log_loss(y,prediction)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

The training routine

```
learning_rate = 0.01
n_epochs = 20
batch_size = 60
num_rec = X_train.shape[0]
n_batches = int(np.ceil(num_rec / batch_size))
acc_test = 0. #  assign the result of accuracy testing to this variable

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for batch_index in range(n_batches):
            X_batch,y_batch = random_batch(X_train,Y_train,batch_size)
            _,opt = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: X_batch,y: y_batch})
        print("epoch " + str(epoch) + ", Loss= " + \
                      "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        print("Optimization Finished!")
    _, acc_test = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X:X_test,y:Y_test})
```

generates the following output:

> epoch 0, Loss= -6.756775, Training Accuracy= 1.00000 Optimization
>   Finished!
>   [. . .]
>   epoch 19, Loss=
>   -6.769919, Training Accuracy= 1.00000 Optimization Finished!

and the the accuracy on the test set `acc_test` is 1.0.

The batches are generated by

```
def random_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
    np.random.seed(42)
    rnd_indices = np.random.randint(0, len(X_train), batch_size)
    X_batch = X_train[rnd_indices]
    y_batch = y_train[rnd_indices]
    return X_batch, y_batch
```

the input shapes are

```
print(X_batch.shape,y_batch.shape,X_test.shape,Y_test.shape) 
>(60, 3) (60, 1) (2500, 3) (2500, 1)
```

Obviously, the accuracy on the training and test tests can't be correct. Where could be the problem in the network, training or evaluation procedure?

Comment: You're positive X_train and X_test are split?

Comment: Yes, they are disjoint. I can't post the complete data generation procedure here, though. Since training accuracy is 1 from the first epoch, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: What is the shape of your input?

Comment: print(X_batch.shape,y_batch.shape,X_test.shape,Y_test.shape) -> (60, 3) (60, 1) (2500, 3) (2500, 1)

Comment: When you set np.random.seed(42), you will make the same batch every time.

Comment: That is not true:

for i in range(3):
     X_batch,y_batch = random_batch(X_train,Y_train,batch_size)
     print(X_batch[0,:])   

generates

[ 0.68665234 -0.02981068 -0.33274321]
[-0.6869842  -0.50021361 -0.02296329]
[ 0.06472047 -0.39327144 -0.21432185]

Comment: I'm not sure then

Answer (score 0):

The model is overfitting due to which you are getting abnormally high accuracy at initial epochs, to avoid overfitting you can use regularization methods or increase dataset by augmenting. Use ImageDataGenerator for augmentation, it will provide images to model in batches. Try setting dropout to 0.2. Enable early stopping in callbacks, it will terminate training when model performance degrades. Try playing with patience in early stopping.